# Other menu untoggle onclick

Tags: javascript

I am making hamburger buttons for small devices for my site. on one page I need two of them under eachother. I got this function for the button, I duplicated the function for the second button because otherwise it would not toggle both of them.

Now What I would like is for the buttons to go back to untoggled when you click the other one. I am not super at Javascript so I was wondering if someone could help me. This is the site page I'm working on: http://koekhuys.commteam.nl/bossche-koek/

```
 ( function() {
        var container, button, menu, links, subMenus;

        container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation');
        if ( ! container ) {
            return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    subMenus = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

    // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
    for ( var i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
        links[i].addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocus() {
        var self = this;

        // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
        while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

            // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
            if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                    self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                } else {
                    self.className += ' focus';
                }
            }

            self = self.parentElement;
        }
    }
} )();
```

and this is the other function. I just duplicated it and added the id of the other menu.

```
( function() {
    var container, button, menu, links, subMenus;

    container = document.getElementById( 'product-navigation');
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    subMenus = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

    // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
    for ( var i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
        links[i].addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocus() {
        var self = this;

        // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
        while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

            // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
            if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                    self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                } else {
                    self.className += ' focus';
                }
            }

            self = self.parentElement;
        }
    }
} )();
```

I was thinking to do something with the "self" variable, but I do not have the knowlegde

This is the HTML for the menu's

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

other menu:

```
 <nav id="product-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"></button>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product', 'menu_id' => 'product-menu' ) ); ?>

                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Can i see your HTML / CSS code related to the menu. I want to see the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, do you want a jquery option or vanilla JS? You tagged both but the code has no jquery in it.

Comment: Thank you, hold on a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the code, but I believe this will work. I tried to DRY out the code as much as possible. Let me know if you have questions.

Vanilla JS

```
(function(){

    // Boolean Checks to stop propagation
    var STOPproductNav = false;
    var STOPsiteNav = false;

    // Grab Container Handles
    var productNav = document.getElementById('product-navigation');
    var siteNav = document.getElementById('site-navigation');
    if ( !productNav ) { STOPproductNav = true };
    if ( !siteNav ) { STOPsiteNav = true };

    // Grab Button Handle
    var btnproductNav = productNav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    var btnsiteNav = siteNav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( typeof btnproductNav === 'undefined') { STOPproductNav = true };
    if ( typeof btnsiteNav === 'undefined') { STOPsiteNav = true };

    // Grab UL Handle
    ulproductNav = productNav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
    ulsiteNav = siteNav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide Menu Button if menu doesn't exist
    if( typeof ulproductNav === 'undefined' ){
        btnproductNav.style.display = 'none';
        STOPproductNav = true;
    };
    if( typeof ulsiteNav === 'undefined' ){
        btnsiteNav.style.display = 'none';
        STOPsiteNav = true;
    };

    // Set default attributs if the menu exists
    if( !STOPproductNav ) { initNavMenu( ulproductNav ); }
    if( !STOPsiteNav ) { initNavMenu( ulsiteNav ); }

    btnproductNav.onclick = function(){
        // Hide Opposite menu if it exists
        if ( !STOPsiteNav ){
            siteNav.className = siteNav.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            btnsiteNav.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            ulsiteNav.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        }
        // Call Toggle Menu
        toggleMenu(productNav,btnproductNav,ulsiteNav);
    }
    btnsiteNav.onclick = function(){
        // Hide Opposite if it exists
        if ( !STOPproductNav ){
            productNav.className = siteNav.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            btnproductNav.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            ulproductNav.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );          
        }
        // Call Toggle Menu
        toggleMenu(siteNav,btnsiteNav,ulsiteNav);           
    }

    if( !STOPproductNav ) { focusFix( ulproductNav ); }
    if( !STOPsiteNav ) { focusFix( ulsiteNav ); }



    // Toggle Menu
    function toggleMenu(containerID, buttonID, menuID) {
        if ( -1 !== containerID.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            containerID.className = containerID.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            buttonID.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menuID.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            containerID.className += ' toggled';
            buttonID.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menuID.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Set default attr and add nav-menu to class
    function initNavMenu(menuID){
        menuID.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        if ( -1 === menuID.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
            menuID.className += ' nav-menu';
        };
    };

    // focus fix
    function focusFix(menuID){
        // Get all the link elements within the menu.
        links    = menuID.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
        subMenus = menuID.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

        // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
        for ( var i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
        }

        // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
        for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            links[i].addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
            links[i].addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
        }

    };

    // Toggle Focus
    function toggleFocus() {
        var self = this;

        // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
        while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

            // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
            if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                    self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                } else {
                    self.className += ' focus';
                }
            }

            self = self.parentElement;
        }
    }   


})();
```

Comment: Wow thank you for taking the time, It still seems to have some bugs, you can see the result of using your funtion here: http://koekhuys.commteam.nl/bossche-koek/

Comment: I had the toggle function backwards. Try that. I edited the code.

Comment: BTW, this code is meant to replace everything in your navagation.js file. Don't just append this code to the end.

Comment: You are amazing! I will studie your code and maybe one day do this myself. Many thanks to you sir.